# Is it possible to pass isActive property to its children in NavLink

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx, tailwind-css

I am using the `<NavLink>` component in my navbar. I have a heart Icon inside the `<NavLink>` component and I want it to get filled when it is in, active state and in, inactive to show only the stroke. I am using Tailwind CSS and heroicons. Is it possible to pass the isActive property of `<NavLink>` to its child in this case the icon?

Here is the code snippet for reference.

```js
<NavLink
    to="favorite"
    className={({isActive}) => "text-red-400  ${isActive ? "" : ""}"
>
    <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        className="w-6 h-6" //${parentProperty? "fill-current" : ""}
        fill="none"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        stroke="currentColor"
    >
        <path
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeWidth={2}
            d="M4.318 6.318a4.5 4.5 0 000 6.364L12 20.364l7.682-7.682a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364-6.364L12 7.636l-1.318-1.318a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364 0z"
        />
    </svg>
</NavLink>
```

Thank You.

Comment: Looks like you are using version 5 of `react-router-dom`, is this correct? I don't think there's a way to pass the `isActive` value to children, but the children may be able to use the active classname of the `NavLink` in a CSS selector and conditionally apply CSS styling.